# Configuring IIS7 404 page when using IIS7 urlrewrite module

Tags: .net, iis7

I've got custom errors to work for .aspx page like: `www.domain.com/whateverdfdgdfg.aspx`

But, when no .aspx url is requested, (like `http://www.domain.com/hfdkfdh4545`) it results in an error:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>   The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I have this in my web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/error/1" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/404.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

404.aspx exists, since the above DOES work when requesting non-existent .aspx pages...

I also configured the errorpages in IIS7:
Status code: 404
Path: /404.aspx
Type: Execute URL
Entry type: Local

My websites application pool setting is "ASP.NET v4.0"

Now why is this still not working?

Comment: Probably belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the following?

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
</system.webServer>
```

Here are a couple of references on error pages:

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpErrors

http://blogs.iis.net/ksingla/archive/2008/02/18/what-to-expect-from-iis7-custom-error-module.aspx